# NDB JsonProperty and Cloud Datastore library compatibility

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb, app-engine-flexible

I have code running on Standar GAE using NDB and code running in flexible env using Google Cloud datastore library. Both accessing to the same entities.

I have problems dealing with ndb.JsonProperty. As far as I read those properties are stored as blob, so I tried to simulate that property using cloud library. Before store the value I do the following:

```
value_to_store = json.dumps(value, separators=[',',':'])
value_to_store = base64.b64encode(value_to_store)
```

And the opposite when I read a property:

```
read_value = base64.b64decode(from_db_value)
read_value = json.loads(read_value)
```

Everything works fine in this situations:

```
Insert using NDB ---> Read using Cloud Library
Insert using Cloud Library ---> Read using Cloud Library
```

But fails when:

```
Insert using Cloud Library --> Read using NDB
```

What's the right way to store those kind of properties to make them compatibles with NDB?

Thanks.

Comment: Ok, it seems that the value inserted using Cloud Library is saved as String while the one inserted using NDB is a Blob.

So I just need to figure out how to store the value as Blob using cloud datastore library

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I found the solution.

The point is that NDB is storing the value as blob while the library is storing as string.

The solution is just do not encode/decode the string value, the library will do it and will store the value as blob, that is what NDB expects.

Writing:

```
value_to_store = json.dumps(value, separators=[',',':'])
```

Reading:

```
read_value = json.loads(read_value)
```

Easy!